# Problems trying to access model output in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I created a function (function may not be the right word) in Keras that builds a deep neural network. As seen below):

```
def create_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, layers=[20, 20, 4], 
                 kernel_init ='he_uniform', bias_init ='he_uniform',
                 batch_norm=True, dropout=True):
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    # layer 1
    model.add(Dense(layers[0], input_dim=x_train.shape[1],
                    W_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),
                    kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                    bias_initializer=bias_init))
    
    if batch_norm == True:
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=momentum, center=True))
    
    model.add(Activation(params['activation']))
    
    if dropout == True:
        model.add(Dropout(params['dropout']))
    
    # layer 2+    
    for layer in range(0, len(layers)-1):
    
        model.add(Dense(layers[layer+1], W_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),
                        kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                        bias_initializer=bias_init))
    
        if batch_norm == True:
            model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=momentum, center=True))
    
        model.add(Activation(params['activation']))
       
        if dropout == True:
            model.add(Dropout(params['dropout']))
       
    # Last layer
    model.add(Dense(layers[-1], activation=params['last_activation'],
                    kernel_initializer=kernel_init,
                    bias_initializer=bias_init))
    
    model.compile(loss=params['losses'],
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.adam(lr=params['lr']),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                        validation_data=[x_val, y_val],
                        batch_size=params['batch_size'],
                        epochs=params['epochs'],
                        verbose=1)
    
    history_dict = history.history
    
    model_output = {'model':model}
    
    return model_output
```

Now if I run this code without making it a function (not putting the def creat_model above) then can do stuff like

```
model.summary()
```

or I can have hist = model.fit() and later get hist.history for access to losses, etc

But if I run the code above I cant do these things even when I put the values that I want after

```
return
```

I have tried putting different things after return like

```
return model
return model, history
return {'model':model, 'history':history}
```

The output I get with the code above is (after running other code):

```
l2_reg = 0.4
momentum = 0.99
seed = 5

create_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, layers=[30, 20, 4], 
                 kernel_init ='he_uniform', bias_init ='he_uniform',
                 batch_norm=True, dropout=True)


Epoch 499/500
614/614 [==============================] - 0s 135us/step - loss: 0.9233 - acc: 0.6515 - val_loss: 1.3652 - val_acc: 0.4470
Epoch 500/500
614/614 [==============================] - 0s 135us/step - loss: 0.9401 - acc: 0.6564 - val_loss: 1.3660 - val_acc: 0.4470
{'model': <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x7f4f3e140b00>}
```

But I still have a problem accessing the model output

```
model_output['model'].summary()
```

Output

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-50b8bc82940b> in <module>()
----> 1 model_output['model'].summary()

NameError: name 'model_output' is not defined
```

Comment: where are you using the return values of `create_model`?

Comment: Sorry I added me trying to use the output. Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: model_output is local to create_model. you can't reference it outside of create_model. you'll need to assign the return value to sth before you can use it, e.g. `m = create_ model(...); m['model'].summary()`

Comment: Trying this now. I will let you know if I get it to work. Regardless I appreciate your help.

Comment: Woo you were right! Thanks! Sorry for the delay

Comment: Now I am going to try to add a dictionary (history_dict = history.history) to my current dictionary ( {'model': model}, and make it {'model':model, 'history_dict':history_dict}. Wish me luck haha

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5986907/joel):

```py
l2_reg = 0.4
momentum = 0.99
seed = 5

m = create_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, layers=[30, 20, 4], 
                 kernel_init ='he_uniform', bias_init ='he_uniform',
                 batch_norm=True, dropout=True)
```

```
Epoch 499/500
614/614 [==============================] - 0s 135us/step - loss: 0.9233 - acc: 0.6515 - val_loss: 1.3652 - val_acc: 0.4470
Epoch 500/500
614/614 [==============================] - 0s 135us/step - loss: 0.9401 - acc: 0.6564 - val_loss: 1.3660 - val_acc: 0.4470


m['model'].summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 30)                1410      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 30)                120       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 30)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 30)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 20)                620       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 20)                80        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 84        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 4)                 16        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 4)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 4)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 20        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,350
Trainable params: 2,242
Non-trainable params: 108
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51801888/4) to the question [Problems trying to access model output in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801888/problems-trying-to-access-model-output-in-keras) by the OP [MikeDoho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9045339/mikedoho) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>